# How is toList available on type A from List.scala?

Tags: scala

In List source : http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_7_final/src/library/scala/List.scala?view=markup

apply method on object List is defined as :

```
 def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

as `A` is not a type how is the `toList` method available ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xs` is defined as `A*` which means that it's a `Seq[A]`.  That's how Scala does varargs: `List()`, `List(3,2,9)`, `List('c','q')`, etc.

The `toList` method comes from the `Seq` class.